# Fatal error: Call to a member function setProfileById() on a non-object

Tags: php, error-handling

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: CI::$analytics
Filename: libraries/MY_Ga_dashboard.php
Line Number: 42
```

line 42 is

```
$this->CI->analytics->setProfileById('ga:'.$this->CI->settings->ga_profile);

Fatal error: Call to a member function setProfileById() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/mydowntown.ca/httpdocs/addons/shared_addons/modules/ga_dashboard/libraries/MY_Ga_dashboard.php on line 42

<?php

class MY_Ga_dashboard {

private $CI;
public $cache_expiration;
public $analytics_start_date;
public $analytics_end_date;


public function  __construct($params)
{
    log_message('info','MY_Ga_dashboard loaded');
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    //start and end date
    $this->analytics_start_date = $params['start_date'];
    $this->analytics_end_date = $params['end_date'];

    $this->use_cached_data = ($this->analytics_start_date == date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 month')) and $this->analytics_end_date == date('Y-m-d')) ? true : false;
    //TODO: move to options/settings
    $this->cache_expiration = 60 * 60 * 6; // 6 hours
}

/**
 * Initialize Analytics for given period
 *
 */
public function init_analytics($start_date=NULL, $end_date=NULL) {

    if ($this->CI->settings->ga_email and $this->CI->settings->ga_password and $this->CI->settings->ga_profile)
    {
        try 
        {
            $this->CI->load->library('analytics', array(

                'username' => $this->CI->settings->ga_email,
                'password' => $this->CI->settings->ga_password
            ));

            // Set by GA Profile ID if provided, else try and use the current domain

            $this->CI->analytics->setProfileById('ga:'.$this->CI->settings->ga_profile);

            if($start_date == NULL) $start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 month')); // Past month
            if($end_date == NULL) $end_date = date('Y-m-d');

            $this->CI->analytics->setDateRange($start_date, $end_date); 

            //$visits = $this->CI->analytics->getVisitors();

        }
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  The error states that the `$this->CI->analytics` attribute referenced on line 42 is not an object. You should start debugging with that.

Comment: Apparently $this->CI is missing analytics attribute. I don't see you initializing this value so the only place that could do this is call to "get_instance()". Could you paste the code of this function? Or check if this function initializes analytics attribute?